# What does “relayed” mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does “relayed” mean here? It means "delivered"?

[image]

When I looked up *relayed* in a [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/relay?q=relayed), I found a definition that said:

> **relayed** (*verb* `trans.`) to tell something you heard :
>   *I relayed the news to the others*.

From the context of the article, though, I can't tell who is relaying this speech. It sounds like they were listening to it as it was being delivered.

Comment: Again, definition 1 at oxforddictionaries.com: "Receive and pass on (information or a message)". Please look up words in the dictionary before you ask about them here.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your question to show you how to ask a better question. Notice how I've shrunk the image to make it less predominant and included some research to more clearly show the possible source of confusion. (To answer your question, the mayor was giving the speech inside the funeral home, while it was being *relayed* outside the funeral home – perhaps through closed-circuit television).

Comment: In addition, a link to the location of the article would great help determine the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to "relay" a message is to deliver it. You can say that someone "relayed a speech", meaning that he stood up and said it, or that he "relayed a letter", meaning that he delivered the letter or caused it to be delivered.

Comment: [Please don't feed the bears](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/9161) - this question doesn't show any research effort and answering it doesn't help the asker understand how to write better questions; it just encourages them to ask more of the same type of off-topic questions. We all want to be helpful, but I think in this case the more helpful thing to do is to provide guidance on how to write a better question.

Comment: Use a dictionary reference, perhaps... It helps explain answers better.